# How to convert tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename() to a string of buffer?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a text editor on a Mac and am having trouble with file saving. I can open, save as and save files but the save function stops working after I call `self.close`.

I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Test1.py", line 43, in save
    self.f1=open(self.file, "w+")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

How can I fix the error?

Here is my code:

```
#modules
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import TclError
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog
import os
#main class
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("PyText")
        #menu for the file cascade
        self.m1=Menu(root)
        self.fm=Menu(self.m1, tearoff=0) 
        self.fm.add_command(label="Open", accelerator="Cmd+O", command=self.open)
        #these two don't work first time...
        self.fm.add_command(label="Save", accelerator="Cmd+S", command=self.save)
        self.fm.add_command(label="Save As", command=self.saveas)
        self.fm.add_command(label="Close", command=self.close)
        self.fm.add_separator()
        self.fm.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
        self.m1.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fm)
        root.config(menu=self.m1)
        #Main text widget
        self.t1=Text(root)
        self.t1.config(width=90, height=40, undo=True, highlightbackground="black", cursor="ibeam")
        self.t1.grid(row=1)
        self.t1.focus_set()
    def saveas(self):
        text = self.t1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        self.savelocation=tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
        self.file=open(self.savelocation, "w+")
        self.file.write(text)
        self.file.close()
    def save(self):
        try:
            text = self.t1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            self.f1=open(self.file, "w+")
            self.f1.write(text)
            self.f1.close()
        except AttributeError:
            text = self.t1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            self.f1=open(self.savelocation, "w+")
            self.f1.write(text)
            self.f1.close()
        except AttributeError:
            text = self.t1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            self.f1=open(self.savelocation1, "w+")
            self.f1.write(text)
            self.f1.close()
        except Exception:
            self.saveas
            raise
    def open(self):
        self.file=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        self.OpenFile=file(self.file) # get a file handle
        self.ReadFile= self.OpenFile.read() # read the file to variable
        self.OpenFile.close() # close file handle
        self.t1.delete(0.0, END)
        self.t1.insert(END, self.ReadFile)
    def close(self):
        self.t1.delete(0.0, END)
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("New file", "Closing old file and creating a new one.")
        self.savelocation1=tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
        self.file=open(self.savelocation1, "w+")
        self.file.close()
root = Tk()
app = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you ran `self.saveas` before you clicked on the button for `save`. The issue is that in `self.saveas` you save `self.file` as the open file, in the lines -

```
self.file=open(self.savelocation, "w+")
```

After that, when you click on `save` , you are trying to use `open()` again on this file, this does not work, you need to pass the `path` of the file (`savelocation` ?) instead of the file itself. Example -

```
def save(self):
    try:
        text = self.t1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        self.f1=open(self.savelocation, "w+")
        self.f1.write(text)
        self.f1.close()
    ... #Rest of the function.
```

---

Also , you `try/except` seems to be messed up, trying to do `except AttributeError` twice does not do what you think it does. It would not catch any  `AttributeError` that was caused in the first `except` block.

And doing `self.saveas` would not call the function, if you want to call the function you should use the *call* syntax  `()`  as `self.saveas()` . Example -

```
def save(self):
    text = self.t1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    try:
        self.f1=open(self.savelocation, "w+")
        self.f1.write(text)
        self.f1.close()
    except AttributeError:
        self.f1=open(self.savelocation1, "w+")
        self.f1.write(text)
        self.f1.close()
    except Exception:
        self.saveas()
```

Comment: No, the first line is in function `saveas`, second is in `save()`. First shows where you are setting `self.file` to a open `file` , second is the fix.

Comment: This is not really very clear, so could you please also post the fixed code? I am getting the exact same error...

Comment: isn't that in the next bit? In `except AttributeError:`?

Comment: No, but your code would never reach there, since it throws TypeError, that is not caught.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "NEW.py", line 82, in save
    self.f1=open(self.file, "w+")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: You are still using `self.file` inside `open()` , why? Like I Said in the answer, that does not work, use `self.savelocation` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93447/discussion-between-jonah-fleming-and-anand-s-kumar).